# Refresh / rebuild .gzip files on amazon S3 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip

All my css and js files are gzipped on the Amazon S3 server, now I have made some modifications to my js and css files, and updated the files through ftp. 
Now the changes are not reflecting on the site as the amazon S3 is serving the old compressed gzip files, I want to know how do I refresh these changed files and create new gzips?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make new zips and upload those as well. S3 is *only* storage, and there is no FTP (although some FTP clients implement support for S3 as well).